# Как загружать и сохранять данные в SQLite (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, node.js, скрипт

**Здравствуйте, я новый пользователь. Я делаю бота для ВКонтакте. И мне нужна помощь**

**Вопрос**: Как мне **правильно** сохранять и загружать данные в ВКонтакте бот Python

**Пожелание**: Мне бы еще скрипт в Python (при желании если можете в NodeJs)

Надеюсь вы поможете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше данные хранить в бд и оттуда уже ими апилировать
На пайтон можно использовать SQLAlchemy чтобы работать с любой бд
Для SQLite вот

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# добавление данных
user = User(name='John', age=25)
session.add(user)
session.commit()

# чтение данных
users = session.query(User).all()
for user in users:
    print(user.id, user.name, user.age)
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли